# how to fix a navbar but only when uploading

Tags: html, css

I hope you can help me. I want my navbar to be fixed but only when I go up, that is to say when it goes down it disappears but at the time of uploading it is visible, like chevrolet.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App Web</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                          <li><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> x</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></span> x</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> z</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: you'll need javascript to detect the scroll position and show the element

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search brought up this article which I think answers your question nicely: [Medium.com/HideHeaderOnScrollDown](https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c).

HTML:

```
<header class="nav-down">
    This is your menu.
</header>
<main>
    This is your body.
</main>
<footer>
    This is your footer.
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding-top: 40px; // same as header height
}
header {
  background: #f5b335;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
// add this class using javascript
.nav-up {
  top: -40px; // same as header height. use variables in LESS/SASS
}
```

JavaScript & jQuery:

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

The JSFiddle for this code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/)

Without seeing more of your code it's hard for me to tailor this example to your exact needs, however you should be able to change a few things, like the padding-top on body to be the same as your header height, to make this work.